# Hide all children divs except first one. When I select a radio option from first div, show the second one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to hide all children divs except first one. When I select a radio option from first div, show the second one. This is my code.

```
<?php if ($options) { ?>
<div class="options <?php echo $this->journal2->settings->get('product_page_options_push_classes'); ?>">
   <h3><?php echo $text_option; ?></h3>
   <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
   <?php if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
   <div class="option form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?> option-<?php echo $option['type']; ?>">
      <label class="control-label"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
      <div id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>">
         <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
         <div class="radio">
            <label>
               <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" class="clickclass" />
               <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
               <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
               (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
               <?php } ?>
            </label>
         </div>
         <?php } ?>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is my output.

[image]

By default, only first set of options "Custom Size" should appear. When I click on any of the radio button, the next set "Custom Style" should appear.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: You need to share the generated html sample

Comment: I got it done. Thankyou @ArunPJohny :)

Comment: please check this third party module. you can use. http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=23337&filter_search=option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            border: 1px solid;
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .secound {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    //you need jQuery
    $(function(){
        $('.first input').change(function(){
            $('.secound').fadeIn('slow')
        })
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="first">
        <p>First Div</p>
        <label>small</label><input type="radio" name="name" value="value">
        <label>medium</label><input type="radio" name="name" value="value1">
        <label>large</label><input type="radio" name="name" value="value2">
    </div>
    <div class="secound">
    <p>Secound Div</p>
        <label>small</label><input type="radio" name="name1" value="value">
        <label>medium</label><input type="radio" name="name1" value="value1">
        <label>large</label><input type="radio" name="name1" value="value2">
    </div>
</body>
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sabeti05/73oprqv0/